# (com.facebook.sdk.login error 304.) Error with FBSDK 4.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement login with Facebook functionality, But I am getting following error in return.

> Login Failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.facebook.sdk.login error 304.)

**Here is my Code**

```
    - (void)loginWithFacebook {
        NSString *const read_actions = @"email";

        [[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]
         logInWithReadPermissions:@[read_actions] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Login Failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             }
             else if (result.isCancelled)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Login Failed due to Cancel");
             }
             else
             {
                 if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:read_actions]) {
                     NSLog(@"Permission granted");

                 }
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: That code works fine for me with the latest version (4.3 as of now) of the SDK, does it fail with the same message after updating to the latest version? Are you running this on an actual device or in the simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I was doing

```
[FBSDKAccessToken refreshCurrentAccessToken:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){}
```

in a background thread during login operation. I removed that and It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 44):

This may because of previous login token not cleared.So before login just logout.

```
NSString *const read_actions = @"email";
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logOut];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[read_actions]
                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Login Failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                   }
                                   else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                       NSLog(@"Login Failed due to Cancel");
                                   } else {
                                       if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:read_actions]) {
                                           NSLog(@"Permission granted");
                                        }
                                   }
                               }];
```

Comment: I tried that but when the refresh access token was called in the background the currentAccessToken was set again. So, I had to stop that thread and add 
[loginManager logOut];
before login attempt as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have not implemented log out, so I just deleted the app, rebuild it and It worked.

Answer (score 29):

**Swift 4 update :**

Everytime you perform something like this

```
    FBSDKLoginManager().login(withReadPermission: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in  // Check for error and then login }
```

```
    //insert this code before the **Login code:** 
    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

and it should work fine :)

Answer (score 5):

Log out the fblogin manager on action which you are performing login just before the login api like:-

```
fbLoginManager.logOut()
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in 
    //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5 update** :
Just refresh your accessToken or logout first.

```
func loginButtonClicked() {
            let loginManager = LoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut()
            loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.email], viewController: nil) { (loginResult) in
                switch loginResult {
                case .success(let grantedPermissions, _, let token):
                    self.returnUserData()
                    print("Success",token,grantedPermissions)
                    break
                case .cancelled:

                    print("Cancel")
                    break
                case .failed(let error):

                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    break
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, But its in swift 2**
**"Logout before login in login button action"**
        let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        login.logOut()

Comment: but need to check current access token